# Should my <script> be inside my <dom-module>?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, web-component

I've been developing with polymer and I've always put my `<script>` tags inside my `<dom-module>` tags. E.G:

```
<dom-module id="">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({});
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

But I've also seen the `<script>` tags put outside of the `<dom-module>` tags. E.G:

```
<dom-module id="">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>

  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({});
</script>
```

Both ways seem to work fine. Which way is considered correct though? Can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dom-module` exists primarily so that the `Polymer()` call can locate template, style, and other dom resources that belong to a registration. The script itself can live anywhere (as long as the corresponding `dom-module` exists a priori).

Folks typically put the script inside the module as it provides a tidy bundle, but it remains optional.